# How to specialize class template based on boolean metafunction?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I have a primary template, which I need to specialize based on based on a meta-function. The usual idiom is like

```
 template<class T,class E = void>
 struct foo { };
 template<class T>
 struct foo<T,std::enable_if_t<is_xxx<T>{}> > {};
```

However, I have  a situation where the primary template is written as

```
template<class T>
 struct foo { };
```

(i.e. without that extra SFINAE placeholder) and I am not allowed to change it. What is the best way to specialize it based on a trait( like I can do that mostly for function template based on return type or additional argument)?

Comment: Mentioning why you cannot modify it may lead to solutions.

Comment: The primary template is not under my control, and not from standard. Note that I do not need that extra E = void thing, if i specialize based on matching like `foo<T*>` , `foo<my_type>` etc .

Comment: How not under your control?  The file is on your hard drive, is it not?  I am serious: what exactly prevents you from changing it?  Other specializations in too much code to change/other binaries you have no access to?  Adversion to having to repatch after updates?  Company policy?  There are lots of reasons, and they may matter.

Comment: I guess it is "Adversion to having to repatch after updates?". This is a boost::vector class from boost::containers (a header only library), for which i have some SIMD specialization. I pull boost directly from git, and really not interested to patch it! And, this is my past time experimental project.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a base class:

```
template<class T, class E = void>
struct foo_base { };

template<class T>
struct foo : foo_base<T, std::enable_if_t<is_xxx<T>{}>> { };
```

Then you move any members of `foo` into `foo_base`.

Comment: From OP question, I think it's safe to assume he can't change `foo` as a whole. ( Maybe a type from a third party library ? )

Comment: So he may specialize it `template<class T>
struct foo<Bar<T>> : foo_base<T, std::enable_if_t<is_xxx<T>{}>> {};`

Comment: Only the primary template can not be changed, the specializations are of course in my hand. So this is not a possible solution form me, as in the example the primary template need to be changed.